# git config --listで表示される設定の削除について

Tags: linux, git

```
$ git config --list
url.https://.insteadof=git://
url.git://.insteadof=https://
```

上記のlistを全て削除したいです。
削除方法のコマンドを教えて頂ければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

おそらく以下のような設定がどこかの設定ファイルで行われています。

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadof=git://
[url "git://"]
    insteadof=https://
```

これを削除するためには、以下のコマンドを実行して**どのファイルでその設定が行われているか**を発見する必要が有ります。

```
$ git config --list --show-origin
# 以下、出力例
file:/home/username/.gitconfig url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadof=https://github.com/
```

上記のような出力が得られるので、該当するファイルを編集（例の場合、 `/home/username/.gitconfig`）すれば意図する設定になるかと存じます。

Comment: 迅速な回答ありがとうございます！
意図した削除がてきました！
ありがとうございます！

Comment: @user26270 質問が、他者の回答によって解決した場合には、質問の承認をお願いできますでしょうか？質問が解決済みであることを、システム的に示すことができます。参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers